# DirectX with VB.NET

Tags: directx

Is there a set of documentation on DirectX (9 or above) that shows the objects, methods, properties, events and samlple code for the use of DirectX (9 or above) with VB.NET?
The most recent SDK includes details for C++ and the "Windows DiectX Graphics documentation" file doesn't contain these details.

Comment: Be aware that Managed DirectX is no longer supported by Microsoft. They want us to use XNA instead. See Filip answer for XNA info.

Comment: On the other hand, XNA only supports DirectX 9, however. For 10 and 11 SlimDX is the only way go to.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most sane idea here is to use SlimDX (a user mantained very good wrapper). Cause remember that Managed DirectX is NO LONGER supported or updated by microsoft. (the support stopped years ago)

http://slimdx.org/

Go take a look at it. It support till DirectX11.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this [VB.NET Managed DirectX Example](http://blogs.vbcity.com/drydo/archive/2005/07/22/4768.aspx) also [The zBuffer](http://www.thezbuffer.com/) is a really good reasource when coding for Managed DirectX and XNA!

Answer (score 0):

A quick google for directx finds the [DirectX developers center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/default.aspx) on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com).
And a quick look around there finds the library page for [DirectX 9.0 for managed code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb318658(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at XNA game studio , it supports all .NET languages currently.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA
Download it here
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23714
It comes with examples.

Comment: Remember that Directx9 is a much beter starting point than Direct 9+x

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use SharpDX. This is much like SlimDX, but faster and created nearly entirely based on header files. You should be able tu use the Library under VB even though it has "Sharp" poiting to C-Sharp in its name. Afaik it is the only solution you can also use for WinRT, and it is nearly a 1:1 adoption of DirectX - so you can use the original MSDN DirectX Documantation. It has capabilitys of DX9, DX10 and DX11.

Also have a look here, for making a decision between SlimDX and SharpDX:

[SharpDX vs SlimDX for game development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004138/sharpdx-vs-slimdx-for-game-development)

I strongly recommend to go for at least either one of them if you just want "managed DirectX" and no higher level API.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses vb.net and C++ dll in visual studio 2017
Features:

- A Universal Windows Project (UWP) in VB that uses a XAML control
  SwapChainPanel.
- Calls a standard win32 dll The dll initializes the
  DirectX, creates a thread and renders the SwapChainPanel from the dll
  code written in C++.
- Compiled in Visual Studio 2017

In Visual Basic add a SwapChainPanel to MainPage.xaml

```
<SwapChainPanel x:Name="swapChainPanel1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt1" Text="Hello from XAML!"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               FontSize="30" />
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="812,484,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="79" Margin="851,561,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="126" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

</SwapChainPanel>
```

In MainPage.xaml.vb

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices      ' Required for dll calling. Our C dll is "dhv.dll"


    <DllImport("dhv.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Private Shared Function D3DInit(ByVal swapChainNative As IntPtr) As UInteger
    End Function

    <DllImport("dhv.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Private Shared Function D3DRender() As UInteger
    End Function



 Dim SwapChainNative As IntPtr


    Private Sub Tst(ByRef s As SwapChainPanel)              ' this is the Vb implementation of QueryInterface on SwapChainPanel cast as IUnknown. See the DirectX documentation
        Dim inspectableIface As IntPtr
        Dim uuid As New Guid("F92F19D2-3ADE-45A6-A20C-F6F1EA90554B")    ' GUID of ISwapChainPanelNative decalred in <windows.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>

        inspectableIface = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(s)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.QueryInterface(inspectableIface, uuid, SwapChainNative)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim r As UInt32
        Tst(Me.swapChainPanel1)
        r = D3DInit(SwapChainNative)
        Me.txt1.Text = r 
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        D3DRender()
    End Sub
```

Create a stabdard Win32 Dll project. It will export two functions. I use a .def file to define the exports. This works very well with vb. No need for other directives such as extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) BOOL __stdcall D3DInit(). Ensure it is called by the linker i.e  /DEF:".\dhv.def"

```
LIBRARY   dhv
EXPORTS  
    D3DInit=D3DInit
    D3DRender=D3DRender
```

A header file Game.h (This code is based on http://www.directxtutorial.com. The Microsoft code is bloated!

```
#pragma once

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace DirectX;

class CGame
{


public:
    ComPtr<ID3D11Device1> dev;              // the device interface
    ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext1> devcon;    // the device context interface
    ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain1> swapchain;      // the swap chain interface
    ComPtr<ID3D11RenderTargetView> rendertarget;    

    ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> Backbuffer;

    UINT32 Initialize();
    void Update();
    UINT32 Render();
    void InitGraphics();

private:
    float ScreenColour;
    UINT ScreenColourI;

    UINT Width, Height;
    UINT32 * TextureData;

};
```

And a Game.cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <wrl/client.h>
#include <d3d11_1.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <windows.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>
#include "Game.h"

DWORD WINAPI renderThread(LPVOID lpParameter);

CGame* pGame;
ComPtr<ISwapChainPanelNative> pSwapChainNative;

UINT32 __stdcall D3DInit(PULONG ptrSwapChainNative)
{
    UINT r;
    pGame = new CGame;
    pSwapChainNative = reinterpret_cast<ISwapChainPanelNative*> (ptrSwapChainNative);
    r = pGame->Initialize();

    return r;
}
UINT32 __stdcall D3DRender(void)
{

    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, renderThread, NULL, 0, NULL);
    return 0;
}


DWORD WINAPI renderThread(LPVOID lpParameter)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        //pGame->Update();
        pGame->Render();
    }
    return 1;
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
UINT32 CGame::Initialize()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    // Define temporary pointers to a device and a device context
    ComPtr<ID3D11Device> dev11;
    ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> devcon11;

    // Create the device and device context objects
    D3D11CreateDevice(
        nullptr,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        nullptr,
        0,
        nullptr,
        0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &dev11,
        nullptr,
        &devcon11);

    // Convert the pointers from the DirectX 11 versions to the DirectX 11.1 versions
    dev11.As(&dev);
    devcon11.As(&devcon);


    // First, convert our ID3D11Device1 into an IDXGIDevice1
    ComPtr<IDXGIDevice1> dxgiDevice;
    dev.As(&dxgiDevice);

    // Second, use the IDXGIDevice1 interface to get access to the adapter
    ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> dxgiAdapter;
    dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(&dxgiAdapter);

    // Third, use the IDXGIAdapter interface to get access to the factory
    ComPtr<IDXGIFactory2> dxgiFactory;
    dxgiAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory2), &dxgiFactory);


    /*
    // set up the swap chain description
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 scd = {0};
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;    // how the swap chain should be used
    scd.BufferCount = 2;                                  // a front buffer and a back buffer
    scd.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;              // the most common swap chain format
    scd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;    // the recommended flip mode
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;                             // disable anti-aliasing



    CoreWindow^ Window = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();    // get the window pointer

    hr = dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow(
    dev.Get(),                                  // address of the device
    reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(Window),        // address of the window
    &scd,                                       // address of the swap chain description
    nullptr,                                    // advanced
    &swapchain);
    */

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 scd = { 0 };
    scd.Width = 1000;           //BUG setting it arbitarily. Needs cleanup. by Ravi
    scd.Height = 800;
    scd.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;           // this is the most common swapchain format
    scd.Stereo = false;
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;                          // don't use multi-sampling
    scd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    scd.BufferCount = 2;
    scd.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
    scd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL; // we recommend using this swap effect for all applications
    scd.Flags = 0;


    hr = dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForComposition(
        dev.Get(),
        &scd,
        nullptr,                                    // allow on any display 
        &swapchain);


    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return  204;
    }

    pSwapChainNative->SetSwapChain(swapchain.Get());


    // get a pointer directly to the back buffer
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), &Backbuffer);


    // create a render target pointing to the back buffer
    dev->CreateRenderTargetView(Backbuffer.Get(), nullptr, &rendertarget);


    // Width and Height
    swapchain->GetDesc1(&scd);
    Width = scd.Width;
    Height = scd.Height;


    TextureData = new UINT32[Width * Height];


    // initialize graphics and the pipeline
    InitGraphics();


    return 0;
}

// this function performs updates to the state of the game
void CGame::Update()
{
}

// this function renders a single frame of 3D graphics
UINT32 CGame::Render()
{
    UINT n, i;
    UINT  * psrc;
/*
    // set our new render target object as the active render target
    devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, rendertarget.GetAddressOf(), nullptr);

    ScreenColour += 0.005f;
    if (ScreenColour >0.9f)
        ScreenColour = 0.0f;

    // clear the back buffer to a deep blue
    float color[4] = {ScreenColour, ScreenColour, ScreenColour, 1.0f};
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(rendertarget.Get(), color);
*/
    psrc = TextureData;
    i = ScreenColourI & 255;

    for (n=0; n<Width*Height; n++)
    {
        *psrc++ = (i<<16) | (i<<8) | i ;
        i++;
        i &= 255;
    }


    ScreenColourI += 1;

    devcon->UpdateSubresource (Backbuffer.Get(), 0, NULL, TextureData, Width*4, 0);

    // switch the back buffer and the front buffer
    swapchain->Present(1, 0);

    return 0;

}

// this function loads and initializes all graphics data
void CGame::InitGraphics()
{
    ScreenColour = 0.0f;
    ScreenColourI = 0;
}
```

And finally don't forget to like D3D11.lib

There you go, the VB window gets painted from the DirectX unmanaged dll at 60Hz!

Ravi