# SharpDX vs SlimDX for game development?

Tags: c#, slimdx, sharpdx

Which one of these offers the best API for game development?  Which library is easier to use, faster, has more documentation?

Comment: This is a "Would a shark beat a gorilla" question. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: This is not a precise question, and as such, will not be popular here.  You might try rephrasing the question to be a programming specific question, or you might find what you are looking for in places like this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23109/is-using-sharpdx-or-slimdx-easier-than-using-directx-directly-from-c

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Both projects support nearly the entire DirectX libraries (though SlimDX does support a bit more in the DirectX 9 space).

SlimDX is very mature, and fully featured.  Some larger scale, commercial games have been written and published using SlimDX.  It also provides more of a "framework" to use, and has more feature-complete documentation.

SharpDX promises slightly better performance in certain scenarios ([see  benchmarks](http://code4k.blogspot.com/2011/03/benchmarking-cnet-direct3d-11-apis-vs.html)).  It's generated directly from the DirectX headers, so is more of a thin DirectX wrapper.

Comment: From what you described the projects should probably swap names :-)